# Git svn fetch, rebase, reset and dcommit functions all hang with no error on one svn branch

Tags: git, svn, git-fetch, dcommit

I have a cloned repository of a large project with a somewhat non standard layout.  Most of my branches work fine, but one of them doesn't.

Any git svn commands just hang and never complete or give errors.

I've tried git reset, etc and nothing works.  I can't fetch, rebase or dcommit on the branch.

Is this something anyone else has seen?  What can I do to fix it?  Google comes up with nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in the Alien-SVN perl library.  I'm running on OSX and it comes with a 1.6.x version of the Perl-Subversion bindings.  I found I was able to reproduce the hang effect with this minimal config:

```
use SVN::Core;
warn $SVN::Core::VERSION;
use SVN::Ra;
SVN::Ra->new('https://example.org/example/project/trunk');
exit;
```

I tried using the built in OSX Perl/CPAN to update the SVN::Core version to no avail.  It went from hanging on exit to segfaulting on startup.  Finally, I just used MacPorts to install git and svn using `sudo port install git-core +svn` as specified in another question about updating the built-in OSX SVN::Core perl library.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to work with your repository with [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) that provides an independent implementation of git-svn, I hope, it won't hang.

Comment: SmatGit crashes when it tries to import our SVN Repo.  Thanks of rate tip though.

Comment: @James Do you see an internal error? In this case, send the resulting bug*-zip files to smartgit@syntevo.com.